# Better query performance for large number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `routine_dhikrs` this table has approximately `~1,696,695` records, the table structure as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `routine_dhikrs` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dhikr_library_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_routine_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `goal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and for Foreign keys and Indexes

[image]

What I want to do is to get the top ten `dhikr_library_id` (I mean count and group by that column). So the result will be as follows.

```
+------------------+-------+
| dhikr_library_id | count |
+------------------+-------+
|               11 | 36595 |
|              110 | 36538 |
+------------------+-------+
```

What I have reached so far is this

```
SELECT RD.dhikr_library_id, COUNT(RD.dhikr_library_id) as COUNT
FROM routine_dhikrs AS RD
WHERE RD.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY RD.dhikr_library_id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query gives me the result correctly and I have no issue so far, the issue for me is that query took about 6.5 seconds to run so, is there any better approach to get these data in a faster way ?

when I run `explain` I get

[image]

Also, I have tried to add `Index` on `dhikr_library_id` but I got the same runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect your index would have marginally reduced the I/O because there are less raw data to chew through but obviously negligible and in any case it would have to go back to the main table for `deleted_at`.  You could try adding `deleted_at` to that index.  Perhaps looking at the query plan would give clues but you might just have slow disks.  If there's a weird inefficiency in MySQL you could try `count(*)` but I'm not hopeful that would achieve much.

Comment: The issue was in `deleted_at` column because it has no `INDEX`

Comment: Specifically, it should be in this order:  `INDEX(deleted_at, dhikr_library_id)`.  The opposite order is not as good.